# Building Attribute Based Recommendation using Solr

Tags: python, django, search, solr, recommendation-engine

I need to match user attributes with solr fields and calculate a cumulative score and retrieve documents based on that custom score.

After reading docs I found couple of ways of doing this task

1) Building Function query using Python and then retrieving its response
   Example: if state == "Uttar Pradesh" then customscore=40

```
statescore:{!func}map(strdist(def(state_exact,""),"Uttar Pradesh",edit),1,1,40,0)

customscore=SUM($statescore,....(sum of all attribute score))
sort=product(customscore*score)
```

2) Creating my custom function in java and using it.Example

```
customscore=customscorefunction(state_exact,...other attributes)&sort=product(customscore*score)
```

Is there any other efficient way of doing this?
Which is correct way of doing this (from above two ways)?

To be specific I have around 10-15 filters and assume that these filters won't change frequently.Also my application is using python and django as framework?